# AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions Error while introspection

Tags: openid-connect, asp.net-core-2.0, aspnet-contrib

I'am writing a test application with asp.net core 2.0, AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server and AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions. I ran into a problem with introspection of the access token. 
When I get my token from /connect/token and send it to my resource server I get the following errors in my server:

```
fail: AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler[0]
      The introspection request was rejected with the following error: invalid_request ; (null)
info: AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler[0]
      The introspection response was successfully returned: {
        "error": "invalid_request"
      }
```

And in my resource server:

```
fail: AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection.OAuthIntrospectionHandler[0]
      An error occurred while validating an access token: the remote server returned a BadRequest response with the following payload: Date: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 17:11:50 GMT
      Server: Kestrel
       {"error":"invalid_request"}.
info: AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection.OAuthIntrospectionHandler[7]
      Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: Authentication failed because the authorization server rejected the access token.
```

This is ConfigureServices method from my Startup class of my resource server (WebApi):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication().AddOAuthIntrospection(
        options =>
        {
            options.Authority = new Uri("http://localhost:64855/");
            options.Audiences.Add("resource_server");
            options.ClientId = "client_id";
            options.ClientSecret = "client_secret";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

This is my protected by AuthorizeAttribute controller in resource server:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OAuthIntrospectionDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] {"value1", "value2"};
    }
}
```

This is Startup class in auth server:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(
                options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
            .AddOAuthValidation(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Audiences.Add("resource_server");
                });

        services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenEndpointPath = "/connect/token";
            options.IntrospectionEndpointPath = "/connect/introspect";
            options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
            options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
            options.Provider.OnValidateTokenRequest = context =>
            {
                if (!context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType() && !context.Request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
                {
                    context.Reject(
                        error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.UnsupportedGrantType,
                        description: "Only grant_type=password and refresh_token " +
                                     "requests are accepted by this server.");

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }

                if (string.Equals(context.ClientId, "client_id", StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
                    string.Equals(context.ClientSecret, "client_secret", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    context.Validate();
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            options.Provider.OnHandleTokenRequest = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType())
                {
                    if (!string.Equals(context.Request.Username, "Bob", StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
                        !string.Equals(context.Request.Password, "P@ssw0rd", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        context.Reject(
                            error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                            description: "Invalid user credentials.");

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }

                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Scheme.Name,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role);

                    identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, "[unique id]");

                    identity.AddClaim("urn:customclaim", "value",
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);

                    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                        new AuthenticationProperties(),
                        context.Scheme.Name);

                    ticket.SetScopes(
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess);

                    context.Validate(ticket);
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

It seems to me that I somewhere missed something when configuring the server and the client, but I can not understand where. 
Or maybe I'm just doing something wrong.
Maybe, I should implement introspect method by myself... don't know(
I already tried to override methods in OpenIdServerConnectProvider, but nothing happened in the end.

Tell me please what can be the problem or what I did wrong.
Thanks.

**UPD: after all fixes, thanks to Pinpoint, this is my working solution:
https://github.com/mstya/Introspection.Sample
I hope it helps someone.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or maybe I'm just doing something wrong. Maybe, I should implement introspect method by myself... don't know( I already tried to override methods in OpenIdServerConnectProvider, but nothing happened in the end.

You forgot to implement the `ValidateIntrospectionRequest` event. Just like `ValidateTokenRequest`, you have to validate the client credentials and call `context.Validate()` if they are valid.

Comment: This is fix my errors in logs, but I still get 401 Unauthorized:(
In logs I got this message:

The introspection response was successfully extracted.
Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: Authentication failed because the access token was not valid for this resource server.

Comment: Also I got a message about data protection:

"trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector[31]
      Performing protect operation to key {} with purposes ('path to proj', 'OAuthIntrospectionHandler', 'AccessTokenFormat', 'Bearer')."

Do I need to configure my data protection?

Comment: The first error message indicates that you configured the introspection handler to require `resource_server` as a valid audience but that no audience was returned by the authorization server. To fix that, remove the configured audience or configure ASOS to add `resource_server` in the authentication ticket using `ticket.SetResources("resource_server")`.