# How to issue and validate jwt from single service endpoint?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have successfully wired up a token-based authorization system between an Angular front end Web Application and a .Net Core Web API back end (for getting data).

Now, I want to consolidate the JWT Logic (generate and validate) into a third Web API .Net Core Project.

How do I 'move' the following logic into a separate Web API for token validation?

**In Startup.cs:**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,

                ValidAudiences = new List<string> { "Audience1", "Audience2" },
                ValidIssuer = "Credit Card oAuth Web API",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"))

            };
        });                        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

**And in the controller:**

```
        [Authorize (Roles = "Credit Card Administrator")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

I want to preserve the logic for Roles (which is working because of claims being set in the JWT like this):

```
var userClaims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, name),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, "user.name@company.com"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, "User Name"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Customer Administrator"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Credit Card Administrator"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Counter Administrator")
            };

            // TODO: Refactor The Following: Get token from oAuth Service (pass in Audience and Claims)
            var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"));
            var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "http://localhost:58726",
                audience: "http://localhost:58726",
                claims: userClaims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                signingCredentials: signinCredentials
            );

            var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);
```

I hope this makes sense and any help is appreciated.

Comment: not sure what do you mean by "want to consolidate the JWT Logic (generate and validate) into a third Web API .Net Core Project." . Are you trying to set up a OpenAuth that runs as a different web server or create a another sub project of solution which running on the same web site ?

Comment: That's exactly what IdentityServer4 does. It separates your authentication server.

Comment: @itminus I think you are correct that I am trying to create an oauth project that will run on another server. I would like to 'pass along' the JWT that is being sent to the data controller over to the oath service for validation.

Comment: @Sasan Thank you. I will look at Identity Server 4. Is that a framework or a 3rd party service?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I 'move' the following logic into a separate Web API for token validation?

The logic that you want to move is part of the ASP.NET Core authentication middleware, which among others, has these responsibilities.

1. read the access token (bearer token) from the HTTP request's `Authorize` header,
2. validate that access token,
3. surface the access token's claims to the `Authorize` attribute.

The access token in this case is encoded as a JWT.

It sounds like you want to do step (2) on a separate server. If that's the case, you're probably looking for **OAuth Introspection.**

There are some [extensions for that here](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions) on GitHub. Also, the [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions Error while introspection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866209/aspnet-security-oauth-extensions-error-while-introspection) question and answer will help you configure those extensions for OAuth Introspection.

Comment: Thank you Shaun. This seems like what I am trying to do. I am hoping the OAth service will accept a JWT token for validation and that my existing 'data' web api project will be able to pass it along. I checked the links quickly (did not fully digest the content in them yet) and I did not see any references to JWT... but I promise I will read them completely soon.

Comment: Where should the 'secret' be stored? Should it be stored in two places? I have three 'projects': oAuth Web Service, the Web Application (client), and the Web API (where the data comes from). Should the secret only be stored in the oAuth Web Server? Or should it be stored in both the client and the oAuth projects?

Comment: What secret specifically do you mean?

Comment: there is a secret that is used to encrypt the credentials in a JWT. It is also the secret shared between the client and auth server. but, in my case, because I have control over all three projects, I am not sure if the secret should be stored in only the oAuth service or in the client as well.

Comment: As far as I can tell, if we're using introspection, then only the authorization server needs to have the JWT secret. It becomes the job of the introspection endpoint to validate/decrypt/parse the JWT. Confirm what I am saying here https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/token-introspection-endpoint/ Don't take my word for it, because I haven't looked deeply at introspection for a while.